# Everytime when i try to acces the (car1.topSpeed) in browser consol bar it shows me an error(car1 is not defined) what to do?

Tags: javascript

This is my code and everytime when I try to access the (car1.topSpeed) in browser console it shows me an error(car1 is not defined) what to do ?

```js
//Creating a constructer for cars
function GeneralCar(givenName,givenSpeed){
    this.name = givenName;
    this.topSpeed = givenSpeed;
    this.run = function(){
        console.log(`${this.name} is running`);
    }
    this.analyze = function(){
        console.log('This car is slower by ${200 - this.topSpeed} than Mercedes')
    }
}
let car1 = new GeneralCar('Tesla',120);          //Here creating a new car with the help of the constructer(GeneralCar).
let car2 = new GeneralCar('Maruti',80);
console.log(car1,car2);
```

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. But please see [ECMAScript template literals like 'some ${string}' are not working](/q/37245679/4642212).

Comment: Please paste the exact error message.

Comment: Is the code you posted inside a function? Then the scope of the variable will be the function, and you won't be able to access it from the top-level console. Set a breakpoint in the function.

Comment: The context where your code is run is needed in order to understand the issue.